# How to make a plain button accept taps across its entire frame?

Tags: swiftui

Under iOS 17.2 this code:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            print("action")
        } label: {
            Text("hello")
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
        }
        .background(Color.yellow.opacity(0.2))
        .buttonStyle(.plain)
        .padding()
    }
}
```

renders this:

[image]

where the light yellow represents the button's frame (I think).

When the button style is `.plain` taps are accepted only on the word "hello".

If I change the button style to `.borderless` taps are accepted anywhere in the frame.

Any ideas on how to make a plain button accept taps anywhere in its frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using this:

```
Text("hello")
    .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
    .contentShape(Rectangle())  // <--- here
```

Comment: Your solution does indeed work with the example code I posted. But when that Button is used in a slightly more complex view hierarchy (in a List with a ForEach) it goes back to its original behaviour.

Comment: I had to go with `.borderless` and control the text color as described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71563367/swiftui-making-a-button-suitable-for-light-and-dark-mode